# Unit test for web API application with dotnet 6

Tags: .net-core, xunit, webapi

I have a web API application with JWT authentication, I want to write test for it, I don't know use XUnit or call APIs with HTTP client!

**XUnit**

```
[Fact]
public async Task Authenticate_WithValidUsernamePassword_ReturnsToken()
{
     //...
}
```

**Http client**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Authenticate_WithValidUsernamePassword_ReturnsToken()
{
   HttpClient _client =...
   var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync("api/v1/admin/Authenticate?....");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **xUnit** like this:

```
[Fact]
    public async Task Authenticate_WithValidUsernamePassword_ReturnsToken()
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/v1/admin/Authenticate?....");
   
        bool result = false;

        if (content == "foo authentication ok") {
            result = true;
        }

        Assert.True(result, $"foo authentication failed Result={result}");
    }
```